# How to get the first alphabet of a string of words

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a columns which has a string of words -

```
df['col1']

0         Anton burt 
1         fred foe hip
2         mark helm schuffer Leib
```

I need a new column "col2" with the first alphabets of all the words in the "col1". What I want is -

```
col1                      col2 

Anton burt                A b
fred foe hip              f f h
mark helm schuffer Leib   m h s L
```

How can I get this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with split by whitespace, seelct first values and join together:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(y[0] for y in x.split()))
#alternative
#df['col2'] = [' '.join(y[0] for y in x.split()) for x in df['col1']]
print (df)
                      col1     col2
0               Anton burt      A b
1             fred foe hip    f f h
2  mark helm schuffer Leib  m h s L
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just do with [`series.str.findall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and [`s.str.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) with a regex `(\b[a-zA-Z])` which finds the first letter of each word:

```
df['col2']=df.col1.str.findall(r'(\b[a-zA-Z])').str.join(' ')
#or df=df.assign(col2=df.col1.str.findall(r'(\b[a-zA-Z])').str.join(' '))
```

---

```
                      col1     col2
0               Anton burt      A b
1             fred foe hip    f f h
2  mark helm schuffer Leib  m h s L
```